# jQuery animate step property

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have a `div` with the class `.container`. When a next button is clicked, I want `.container` to slide off the the screen and when it is halfway off the screen, another `div` will fade or slide in. I was able to get the `div` to slide off the screen, and to bring in the other `div`, however the other `div` only comes in when the `.container` is fully off of the screen (since it I am using the complete parameter).

```
$( ".content" ).animate({
    left: '-875px',
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    complete: function() {
        showPage(page);
    }
});
```

I found that if I use:

```
step: function(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

I am able to get all the values of where the 'left' in animate function is at a certain point. So I can determine where the animate is at when I want the new `div` in. I am unable to put the `showPage(page)` function in the step parameter though. Is there any easy way around this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate both div's but putting a delay for the second div, which is half the total animation time of the first. So if it is halfway the full animation, the other will start.

I made a sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/Yqu4A/2/

```
$("button").click(function() {
var dist = -($(".container").width());
$(".container").animate({
    "left":dist
}, 1000);
$(".container2").delay(500).animate({
    "opacity":1
},500);   
});
```